# How to setup Identity's Cookie Data Protection to use the Azure Storage Data Protector

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When setting up the data protection and Identity, the Identity already needs a built IDataProtectionProvider, while the data protection api doesn't offer this.

ConfigureServices

```
IDataProtectionBuilder protectionBuilder = services
    .AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(storageContainer, "keys.xml");
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.DataProtectionProvider = //NEEDS AN IDataProtectionProvider
}
```

For custom cookies it can be set later, in the Configure:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AutomaticChallenge = false,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    DataProtectionProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IDataProtectionProvider>()
});
```

Relevant docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the above code already works.

Simply telling the data protection to store the keys in Azure seems to automatically resolve the Identity data protector to the same storage.

Only code needed compared to no shared keys:

`services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(tableContainer, "keys.xml");`